# Get value in a post request, Django

Tags: django, string, unicode, django-forms, django-views

am getting the following post data in my django app

```
POST
            Variable                      Value
            csrfmiddlewaretoken    u'LHM3nkrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrdd'
            id                     u'{"docs":[],"dr":1, "id":4, "name":"Group", "proj":"/al/p1/proj/2/", "resource":"/al/p1/dgroup/4/","route":"group", "parent":null'
```

am trying to get the `id` value in variable `id` i.e `"id":4` (the value `4`). When I do `request.POST.get('id')`I get the whole json string. `u'{"docs":[],"dr":1, "id":4, "name":"Group", "proj":"/al/p1/proj/2/", "resource":"/al/p1/dgroup/4/","route":"group", "parent":null'` How can I get the `"id"` in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you are sending is simply a json string.

You have to parse that string before you can access data within it. For this you can use Python's json module (it should be available if you're using Python 2.7).

```
import json
data = json.loads( request.POST.get('id') )
id = data["id"]
```

If you somehow don't have the json module, you can get the simplejson module.

For more details, refer this question : [best way to deal with JSON in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200110/best-way-to-deal-with-json-in-django)

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved me big deal. I've been battling with it for hours, thanks also for the extra information.

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because `id` is string, not dict as it should be. Please provide your template and view code to find source of problem.